# Javascript Tabber Reload

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic, reload

I've got some dynamic content inside a tabber (http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/).

All works fine, but I want to reload the div which contains the tabber. When I do this, using jQuery AJAX, the data updates, but the tabs are no longer formed. Do I have to reload the javascript elements of the page, and if so how do I got about doing this?

Thanks! :)

Sparkles*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX function is probably replacing the contents of the div with new elements (so they lose any initialization that you've done).

In your AJAX callback, just re-initialize tabber. From glancing at their web-page it looks like you just need to call the function `tabberAutomatic(tabberOptions);`

I think something like this will do the trick:

```
$("#myDiv").load("/my/remote/data.json", function(){
    tabberAutomatic();
});
```